# How to run selenium API with dot-net (using c#)

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, nunit

My company ask mt to write a program for testing without using selenium IDE and firefox.
How can I use windowform to build a selenium-base program??
I always only import dll.file to Nunit and test.Now how can I just run in my own program?

Comment: Why can't you use Selenium? Seems like this would be reinventing the wheel? Or do you for some reason need a better wheel :-)

Comment: cause our company write some system cannot be used on the firefox...
Actually,i feel coufused too. they ask me use selenium API.

Comment: Selenium supports most browsers though. You can even use it with IE

Comment: i know.That's why I feel confused.

Comment: Best to get clarification from your team, why they hate selenium? I would suggest, use WatIR, in this case you do not need to reinvent the wheel. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I run Selenium Tests

Download Selenium RC
Launch selenium RC like this:
java -jar [Your path to]\Selenium-server.jar -interactive
--This will launch a Java console application that is your Selenium Server (RC)

Write and run the tests as described in @shenhengbin's article

There is no executable involved in this, and you can use any testing framework to run the tests.

Comment: yap,i am already done this. My colleague use exe to pack a jar to run.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, you can actually use the built in testing framework in VS. TO install Nunit you can download it from their site and add a reference to their dlls in your testing project.